# navigating a image from page to other in mono android

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an `ImageView` and `Button` in an `Activity`, lets call it A. When clicking on the `Button`, I start the image gallery, where I select an image and load that into the `ImageView`.

On the `ImageView` I subscribe to the `Touch` events, where I want to launch another `Activity`, B.

My question is, how can I in `Activity` B get the image, which was selected in `Activity` A? How is data passed fomr `Activity` to another `Activity`?

Here is my code in `Activity` A:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
    _imageView.Touch += TouchMeImageViewOnTouch;
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
    button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
}

private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent = new Intent();
    Intent.SetType("image/*");
    Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
    {
        Uri uri = data.Data;
        _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);

        string path = GetPathToImage(uri);

        Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long);
    }
}

private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri)
{
    string path = null;
    string[] projection = new[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
    using (var cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
    {
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(
                Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
        }
    }
    return path;
}

private void TouchMeImageViewOnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
{
}
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Dumping all of your code will not help. Only show the relevant parts.

Comment: my question is-there is an event on image touch-TouchMeImageViewOnTouch(),after touching how can I pass the image to another page...

Comment: Please edit your question and actually put it there. And remove all non-relevant code.

Comment: I have edited my question...pls check and help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TouchMeImageViewOnTouch` method, you will need to start `Activity` B. This is done by creating an `Intent`. This `Intent` can hold extra stuff the `Activity` you launch (B), will be able to get hold of.

So I see that you already found out how to get the path to the image, which you simply can pass along to `Activity` B in the `Intent` which is done like this:

```
private void TouchMeImageViewOnTouch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof (MainActivity));
    intent.PutExtra("imagePath", path);

    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in `Activity` B you can get the path with:

```
Intent.GetStringExtra("imagePath");
```

Then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: HI Guys,I am new to mono.Could you please tell me ,How u have done in acticity B.

Comment: In your `OnCreate` override you can just do `var someExtra = Intent.GetStringExtra("imagePath");`.

Comment: Thanks @cheesebaron..it worked...one more query..is there a way to navigate a image from activityA to activityB then activity B to activityC(same image)

Comment: @user2792312 create a new StackOverflow question for that with a more detailed description.